# PHP 5.4 Missing sqlite registered save handler for session management

Tags: php, sqlite, session

I am migrating our application from a server running PHP 5.3 to a new server running PHP 5.4. In our old setup we were using PHP's built in sqlite session handler per the following lines in our php.ini

```
session.save_handler = sqlite
session.save_path = /some/dir/sessions.sqlite
```

This works great for us and we'd like to continue to do the same thing on the new platform. The problem I am experiencing is that `sqlite` seems to no longer be a valid option for the built in save handlers.

On the older server I would see:

```
[root@localhost ~]# php -i | grep "Registered save"
Registered save handlers => files user sqlite
```

And on the new server I get

```
[root@localhost ~]# php -i | grep "Registered save"
Registered save handlers => files user
```

Now I have been scouring the google for articles about this and it appears that in PHP 5.4 they have discontinued the sqlite extension in favor of the sqlite3 extension. That's fine and I have sqlite3 working but it still isn't an option as a registered save handler.

My boss has mandated that we do not use the `files` handler because of problems it has caused for us in the past. Is my only option really to use a custom handler? I would think that ideally `sqlite` or at least `sqlite3` would still be valid handlers.

If I am misreading the situation I would be glad to hear about it. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are you sure that your 5.4 is built with sqlite support?  You may need to install that separately.

Comment: Looks like this is just a known issue in 5.4: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53713&edit=1